# Linear transformations on finite dimensional spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The problem is:

> Let $U,V$ be $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces such that $\dim_\mathbb{K} V < \dim_\mathbb{K} U < \infty$, and $T:U \to V$ a linear transformation. Show that there exists $u \in U, u \neq 0$, such that $T(u) = 0$.

I tried to solve it thinking in terms of an arbitrary base $\mathcal{B}$ of $U$. Essentially, I tried to show that there is $u \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $T(u) = 0$, but couldn't go much further. Is it possible to obtain such $u$?

Any other insights on the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible. Take a basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ of $U$. Now suppose $T(e_1),\ldots,T(e_n)$ are linearly independent. That would mean that $n\leq dim_\mathbb{K}V$ which contradicts the fact that $dim_\mathbb{K}V <n$.

So the $T(e_1),\ldots,T(e_n)$ not being linearly independent means there exist $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in \mathbb{K} $ not all zero s.t.

$$ 0=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i T(e_i). $$

Using the linearity of $T$ you obtain:

$$ 0=T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i\right) $$

and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i=u\neq 0$ is the vector you were looking for.

Comment: A set of vectors can be linearly independent while not being a basis (it then can be expanded to one). You probably meant "being independent" instead of "being a basis".

Comment: @Abstraction You are completely right. I edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the First Isomorphism Theorem:
$$U/\ker T\approx T(U)\subset V$$
and
$$\dim U - \dim\ker T = \dim T(U) \le \dim V,$$
$$\dim\ker T \ge \dim V - \dim U > 0.$$